# Testing whether a method's return type is a number?

Tags: java, class, reflection, casting, numbers

As part of an autograder for a class I'm teaching, I would like to be able to test whether a student wrote a method whose return type was a numeric type (`int`, `double`, `Integer`, `Double`, etc.). I tried to do this as follows:

```
Method m = StudentClass.class.getDeclaredMethod(/* ... */);
return Number.class.isAssignableFrom(m.getReturnType());
```

This code will work correctly if the return type of the method is `Integer` or `Double`, but not if it's `int` or `double`. This confuses me, since it's legal to write

```
Number n = 137; // Assign an int to a Number
```

and

```
Number n = 1.608; // Assign a double to a Number
```

Why doesn't the code I've written above correctly if the method returns `int` or `double`? Aside from hardcoding tests to see if the result is `int`, `long`, `char`, `double`, etc., what can I do to test if the method returns a result of numeric type?

Thanks!

Comment: [Ideone](https://ideone.com/LCIiho) sample for those who want to play.

Comment: You can use [`Integer.TYPE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#TYPE), [`Double.TYPE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#TYPE) etc: https://ideone.com/gBqT3H. It's not elegant having to enumerate them all, since there is no inheritance relationship between them, but it gets the job done. (I'll answerify this in a bit if it helps.)

Comment: Another option is checking [`Class.isPrimitive()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isPrimitive()), and blacklisting the primitive types that aren't numeric, and maybe adding the nonprimitive ones that are. I suppose your fundamental problem is that Java, at the language level, does not really care about "numeric" as a concept.

Comment: Downvoter - is there anything wrong with this question that I can try to improve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution does not touch the underlying cause but instead provides a workaround. It is not very elegant but considering it should never change (not unless Java somehow adds a new numeric type), I'm willing to put up with it for clarity reasons.

```
public class Main {
    private static List<String> validTypes = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("int");
        add("Integer");
        add("double");
        add("Double");
        add("long");
        add("Long");
        add("float");
        add("Float");
    }};
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        for(Method m : main.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()){
            System.out.println(m.getName() + ": " + validTypes.contains(m.getReturnType().getSimpleName()));
        }
    }

    public static int mInt(){ return 1; }

    public static Integer mInteger(){ return 1; }

    public static double mDouble(){ return 1.0; }

    public static Double mDoubleD(){ return 1.0; }
}
```

Output

```
main: false
mDoubleD: true
mInt: true
mInteger: true
mDouble: true
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that int, long, double are primitives and not objects at all and do not inherit from Number. Its possible but unlikely someone could role there own version of a number class that also did not inherit from number which could make this question harder to answer but generally you would be ok yo do your number check and then also hardcode the primitives.

An alternative is to actually call the method with a value and check that the value back is numeric doing a similar thing to your cast above and checking for the exception or using http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html isNumber on the String.valueof result. Of course its eniterly possible that someone could still write a class/method that could do the correct thing but fail any of these checks.

Comment: All of those primitive types do have to have a corresponding `Class` object though.